# Spring Security Custom User Authorization Tables

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to use Spring Security 3.1  in my web app. I have started off with following this particular [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/).

I am using the technique used here where in authentication provider is a datasource

```xml
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"

           users-by-username-query="
              select email,password 
              from usr where email=?" 

           authorities-by-username-query="
              select u.email, ur.authority from usr u, usr_roles ur 
              where u.usr_id = ur.usr_id and u.email =?  " 

        />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

So if you notice I am using the email as my username and I do not have a enabled column.

This does not seem to work.

My login form looks like

```html
<form name="f" action="<c:url value="j_spring_security_check" />" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>User:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="j_username" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="j_password" />
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
                <input name="reset" type="reset" />
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Please advise as to how to get this working or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve it myself. I have modified the authentication-manager configuration as follows

```xml
<authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>

            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"

           users-by-username-query="
              select * from (select email as username,password,1 as enabled 
              from usr) where username=?" 

           authorities-by-username-query="
             select * from
            (select u.email username, ur.authority AUTHORITY 
            from usr u, usr_role ur 
              where u.usr_id = ur.usr_id) where  username = ? " 

        />
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```